# Произошла одна или несколько ошибок. ---> Microsoft.Build.Shared.InternalErrorException: MSB0001: Internal MSBuild Error

Tags: msbuild

Иногда падает MsBuild, кто может подсказать как решить проблему?
Можете подсказать как понять что именно вызывает ошибку при сборке?

---

> UNHANDLED EXCEPTIONS FROM PROCESS 384:
>   13.09.2015 15:39:22 Microsoft.Build.Shared.InternalErrorException: MSB0001: Internal MSBuild Error: We shouldn't be accessing the
>   ProjectInstance when the configuration is cached.    в
>   Microsoft.Build.Shared.ErrorUtilities.ThrowInternalError(String
>   message, Exception innerException, Object[] args)    в
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.BuildRequestConfiguration.get_Project()    в
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.BuildRequestConfiguration.GetAfterTargetsForDefaultTargets(BuildRequest
>   request)    в
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.BuildRequestEngine.IssueBuildRequests(BuildRequestEntry
>   issuingEntry, FullyQualifiedBuildRequest[] newRequests)    в
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.BuildRequestEngine.IssueUnsubmittedRequests() 
>   в
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.BuildRequestEngine.<>c__DisplayClass59_0.b__0()
>   в
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.BuildRequestEngine.<>c__DisplayClass67_0.b__0()
>
> ## ...
>
> 13.09.2015 15:39:22 System.AggregateException: Произошла одна или несколько ошибок. ---> Microsoft.Build.Shared.InternalErrorException:
>   MSB0001: Internal MSBuild Error: MSB0001: Internal MSBuild Error: We
>   shouldn't be accessing the ProjectInstance when the configuration is
>   cached....

Comment: Отформатируйте текст и убирете такое кол-во информации, оставьте только основное

Comment: пожалуйста, уточните вопрос - опишите хотя бы как воспроизвести проблему. а еще лучше - запостите баг на [microsoft connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/)

Comment: Эта ошибка возникает при простом построении проекта. Причем если через студи запускать частота воспроизведения 1 раз из 10 запусков. А если через командную сроку то 8 раз из 10-ти запусков. При этом падает MsBuild.
Скорее всего Вы правы, нужно будет запостить на microsoft connect